# Most efficient (computationally) orbit propagation for simplified J2 effects

Tags: orbital-mechanics, low-earth-orbit, orbital-elements

I am looking into modeling large scale constellation (hundreds of satellites) and there coverage over earth given a defined conical FOV. The simplified process is a user defines:

1. Constellation (starting with walker-delta)
2. Sensor FOV
3. Evaluation Time period, and time step
4. Grid density (how many points spaced out on earths surface)

And effectively the flow logic is at every deltaT, propagate the satellites and get their position coordinates, calculate their LOS and FOV access to the points on the ground and continue the process.

Now currently I have implemented a basic two body propagator which takes orbital elements, uses newtons method for the various "anomaly" calculations and conversions to effectively propagate using the orbital elements and then convert to cartesian at the end of each step.

I feel like this is an ineffecient method, since I have a fixed time step, and I also have the RV (position and velocity) componentes at the end of a time step. Is there a method to propogate in RV terms, instead of orbital elements that would be more accurate?

Some assumptions in my program:

1. Only care about simplified J2 effects
2. DO NOT care about drag
3. Only dealing with LEO and MEO circular or elliptical orbits.

I think the assumptions I have entering into the analysis allow for very efficient calculations.

Also when I say time step, I am dealing with the order of 10's of seconds to several minutes over several months.

Comment: This is a great question! By the way if there were no $J_2$ and you were looking at strictly Kepler orbits, then while Newton's method is necessary to get $\theta(t)$, [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/43237/12102) explains that $t(\theta)$ can be found exactly analytically (you don't need to converge). Newton's method is so darn fast though that it may be faster than switching back and forth between $\theta(t)$ and $t(\theta)$.

Comment: About your question, I think here you are only asking for a way to incorporate $J_2$ effects into a cartesian [ODE solving context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation), is that right? I always refer back to [Equation 15 in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geopotential_model#The_deviations_of_Earth.27s_gravitational_field_from_that_of_a_homogeneous_sphere) (e.g. [1](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/23409/12102), [2](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/34183/12102), [3](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/34181/12102)).

Comment: For "most efficient" do you mean computationally fastest or *easiest and quickest to write and get running?* If it's the latter then a few dozen lines of Python is all you need. If its the former then a compiled language may be necessary. Since you have a constellation, then you may gain computational speed by vectorizing; propagating groups of spacecraft together. The size of the group will have an optimum; too larger and it will slow down due to constant swapping due to limited on-chip cache size in your CPU.

Comment: @uhoh by most efficient I am looking for computational the fastest. I will be using fortran to write the analysis code. I feel like any form of integration of ODE would be slower then the original method I mentioned. It may be that using orbital elements and converting to cartesian coordinates may just be the fastest, but wanted to explore options.

Comment: I see, well once you add $J_2$ then the original method will probably require a perturbation approach like the way that [TLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-line_element_set)s are propagated in [SGP4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_perturbations_models). Even though Kepler orbits are 2D the problem with $J_2$ is now 3D and it will perturb and evolve most/all of the seven orbital elements. You can start reading about it [here](https://celestrak.com/publications/AIAA/2006-6753/) for example.

Comment: Modern computers, even laptops, may be much faster if you can vectorize the problem (propagate many satellites at the same time) because of the architecture of modern CPUs and use of multithreading. Languages like Python and others call ODE solvers which themselves are written in compiled languages like FORTRAN and C and are likely to already be optimized to take advantage of these, but if you write your own you may have to implement this yourself. Note also that since $J_2$ is axisymmetric, orbits that only differ by longitude of ascending node will evolve identically.

Comment: see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_(astronomy)#Mathematical_analysis and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_(astronomy) Perturbations are one way to go but there's a lot to read and learn. This was all developed before modern computers and ODE solvers existed. I think you will be better off using an ODE solver in cartesian coordinates because as you add more effects later on it will be straightforward and easy to add them as a small modification. Those include higher order gravitational terms, drag, Sun, Moon etc.